# How can I use win32 vmi classes in c++?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I would like to monitoring harwares just like in C#, but I cannot find any articles, how can I use the win32 classes in visual c++.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394558(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're referring to WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation) classes, for C++ usage and examples see here: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394582(v=vs.85).aspx